# Hadoop ResourceManager Can Not Start

Tags: hadoop

I got the following error, but `netstat` shows 8088 is not in use.

This is a 3 node cluster, Namenode, Jobtracker, Datanode running on different EC2 instance

```
2014-02-04 02:49:43,519 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: Error starting http server
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startWepApp(ResourceManager.java:623)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:872)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Port in use: jobtracker.hdp-dev.XYZ.com:8088
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.openListener(HttpServer.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:257)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.openListener(HttpServer.java:738)
        ... 6 more
2014-02-04 02:49:43,522 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at name01.hdp-dev.XYZ.com/10.xxx.xxx.xxx
************************************************************/
```

Comment: How did you use netstat command and with what options?

Comment: I used 'netstat -tulpn'

Answer (score 0):

On a Debian-based system, you can run something like 
**apt-cache policy zookeeper** at the terminal. That command will list all the repositories where the package zookeeper is available.
If the package zookeeper is available from two repositories or more: eg :Ubuntu’s Raring Universe Repository and the CDH repository. So, you have a problem.
Specially understanding that this can be a package mix/match issue

**Solution is** : Create a file at **/etc/apt/preferences.d/cloudera.pref** with the following contents:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Cloudera, l=Cloudera 
Pin-Priority: 501
```

No **apt-get update** is required after creating this file.
Here, the default priority of packages is 500. By creating the file above, you provide a higher priority of 501 to any package that has origin specified as “Cloudera” (o=Cloudera) and is coming from Cloudera’s repo (l=Cloudera), which does the trick..
Hope this helps..